# getting items greater than a certain item in prolog

Tags: prolog

let's say I have the following data:  in the form of mers(CONTINENT,COUNTRY,CASES,DEATHS)

```
mers("middle east", "kingdom of saudi arabia", 1863, 750).
mers("middle east", "united arab emirates", 92, 13).
mers("middle east", "qatar", 19, 5).
mers("middle east", "jordan", 35, 14).
```

and I want to return the countries that have more cases than jordan, how would I go about that in prolog?

so the query should return kingdom of saudi arabia, united arab emirates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findall/3` for this, which will return a list of all of the locations with CASES values higher than those for "jordan". The following assumes you have only 1 value corresponding to "jordan".

```
findall(Loc, (mers(_, "jordan", X, _), mers(_, Loc, Cases, _), Cases>X), Y).
```

In the above, `Loc` is the variable which will bind to each location you want. In the middle argument, your conditions are:

```
mers(_, "jordan", X, _), mers(_, Loc, Cases, _), Cases>X
```

where X is the value for "jordan", Loc are the other locations you want to return, and Cases is the value that must be above X.

The output is:

```
Y = ["kingdom of saudi arabia", "united arab emirates"].
```

Comment: thank you so much, would it be any different if I wanna return lets say another continent that is Europe, and I wanna return the continent that has more cases than europe 

so if I had 
mers("europe","uk", 5,3).

then I will return middle east because middle east has more cases. would it be different than this code?

Comment: It is a bit different, but if you were to replace "jordan" for "europe" and make it the first argument of the first findall, and then change the Loc variable to bind the first argument of the second, then you'd get a list of all the continents with more cases than "europe" (though, one copy of the continent name per solution, so you'd have multiple copies of e.g. "middle east" in a list).